# Why did clones like commander Rex and Wolffe not have the troops in their unit's inhibitor chips removed?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

To me, it makes sense that Rex, Wolffe, and Gregor would have some other clone troopers remove their inhibitor chips, instead of practically *letting* them kill the Jedi. It just doesn't make sense.

**Why did they not have the troops in their unit's inhibitor chips removed?**

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This is a nice first question! Don't forget to take the [tour]!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Rex had to be very careful to avoid being killed.**

Without going into full details, in *Clone Wars* [S06E02](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Conspiracy) , clone trooper [Fives](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CT-5555) discovers inhibitor chips, in [S06E03](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fugitive) he manages to remove it from his head with quite complicated surgery. In [S06E04](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Conspiracy) Fives is directly told by Palpatine some parts of anti-Jedi conspiracy. We never know how much, because this is not shown on screen. Fives manages to tell Rex about chips, that conspiracy against Jedi exists, and that Chancellor is involved. After that, Fives is killed, ironically by other clones.

Considering what he saw and heard, Rex had to move very carefully. He first had to check if he really has inhibitor chip, then find medical droid willing to extract it discretely. Rex had to be cautious to avoid ending up like Fives. Therefore, he only told about chips to trusted friends, because other clones, obedient as they were, would probably report him in and he would end up killed. Note that Kamino cloners were forced to admit existence of inhibitor chips to Jedi after discovery made by Fives. But they invented cover story that inhibitor chips serve to control overly aggressive behavior of clones, and that removing them would make clones go mentally unstable (like Fives supposedly did) . So Rex removing his chip publicly would probably got him in position of being declared insane, and therefore target for elimination.